# Quotient Spaces and Quotient Topologies

Tags: functional-analysis, topological-vector-spaces

Let $X$ be a topological vector space (not necessarily Hausdorff), with topology $\tau$, and $M, N$ linear subspaces of $X$. Consider the quotient map $\pi:X \rightarrow X/N$, which associates to each $x \in X$ the coset $x + N \in X/N$.

Define the map $\Phi: M /(M \cap N) \rightarrow \pi(M)$ by associating to each coset $x+ (M \cap N)$, with $x \in M$, the coset $x+N$. It is immediate to see that $\Phi$ is well defined (that is $\phi(x+(M \cap N))$ does not depend on the particular $x$ chosen in the coset $x+ (M \cap N)$) and that it is an isomorphism of vector spaces.

Moreover, in Note (1) below, it is shown that $\Phi$ is continuous. Anyway, in general $\Phi$ is not a homeomorphism: in Note (3) below a counterexample is given in which $X$ is Hausdorff and $M$ is closed.
Can you find a counterexample in which $X$ is Hausdorff and both $M$ and $N$ are closed?

Thank you very much in advance for your attention.

NOTE (1) Suppose that $V$ is open in $\pi(M)$, that is $V=E \cap \pi(M)$, with $\pi^{-1}(E)=W \in \tau$. Then $\Phi^{-1}(V)= \{ x + (M \cap N) \in M/(M \cap N): x + N \in V \}$. So, if $\rho : M \rightarrow M/(M \cap N)$ is the quotient map (which associates to $x \in M$ the coset $x + (M \cap N)$), then we have 
\begin{equation}
\rho^{-1}(\Phi^{-1}(V))= \{ x \in M : x+N \in V \}= M \cap W.
\end{equation}
 So $\rho^{-1}(\Phi^{-1}(V))$ is an open set of $M$, and we conclude by definition of quotient topology that $\Phi^{-1}(V)$ is an open set of $M/(M\cap N)$.

NOTE (2) If $N \subset M$, then $\Phi$ is open, so it is a homeomorphism.  Indeed in this case $M \cap N = N$. Let $F \subset M/N$, with $\rho^{-1}(F)=M \cap W$ and $W \in \tau$. Put $E= \pi(W)=\pi(W+N)$. We have $\pi^{-1}(E)= W + N \in \tau$, so $E$ is an open set of $X/N$.

Note that we have $M \cap W =M \cap (W + N)$. Indeed if $x \in M \cap W$, then $x+N \in F$, so that $x + n \in \rho^{-1}(F)=M \cap W$ for all $n \in N$. So 
\begin{equation}
\Phi(F)= F = \{x + N \in M/N: x \in M \cap (W+N) \}.
\end{equation}
If $x+N \in \Phi(F)$, then $x \in M \cap (W + N)$, so that $x+N \in E \cap \pi(M)$. Conversely, if $x+ N \in E \cap \pi(M)$, then for some $m \in M$ and $w \in W$, we have $x+N=m+N=w+N$, so that $m \in M \cap (W+N)$, and $x+N=m+N \in \Phi(F)$. We conclude that $\Phi(F)=E \cap \pi(M)$, which is an open set of $\pi(M)$.

NOTE (3) Let $X$ be a Hausdorff TVS, and $M$ a closed linear subspace which is not complemented (for the definition of "complemented subspace" see Rudin, Functional Analysis, Second Edition, Section 4.20, while for example of uncomplemented subspaces see Rudin, cit., pp. 132-138). Let $\{ v_{\alpha} \}$ be a Hamel basis of $M$, and let $\{ w_{\beta} \}$ a subset of $X$ such that $\{ v_{\alpha} \} \cup \{ w_{\beta} \}$ is a Hamel basis of $X$. Let $N$ be the linear subspace spanned by the $\{ w_{\beta} \}$. Then we have $M + N =X$ and $M \cap N = \{0 \}$. Since $M$ is uncomplemented, $N$ cannot be closed. We have $\pi(M)=X/N$ and $M/(M \cap N)= M/\{0 \}$.

Now, let us remember that if $T$ is a TVS and $S$ a linear subspace of $T$, then the quotient space $T/S$ is Hausdorff if and only if $S$ is closed (see e.g. Horvath, Topological Vector Spaces and Distributions, Proposition (5) at p. 105 or Treves, Topological Vector Spaces, Distributions and Kernels, Proposition (4.5) at p. 34). So $X/N$ is not Hausdorff, while $M/ \{0 \}$ is Hausdorff (since $X$ is Hausdorff, also $M$ is Hausdorff, so $\{0 \}$ is a closed subset of $M$). We conclude that $X/N$ and $M/ \{0 \}$ cannot be homeomorphic. So $\Phi$ cannot be a homeomorphism.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I answered my question thanks to the crucial help of Bill Johnson. See my answer in [Subspaces of Quotient Spaces](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/261422/subspaces-of-quotient-spaces/261441#261441).